# Synonymize [openscenegraph] and [osg]?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

<strike>I just noticed that we have two tags for the same scenegraph library. Namely [osg](/questions/tagged/osg) with 29 tags and [openscenegraph](/questions/tagged/openscenegraph) with 48 tags. Often they are even used together. I can go ahead and retag them all [openscenegraph](/questions/tagged/openscenegraph) since that seems to be the most popular.</strike>

I have since gone ahead and retagged everything appropriately. All content tagged [osg](/questions/tagged/osg) was indeed related to OpenSceneGraph. There is no longer any content tagged [osg](/questions/tagged/osg).

Given that the library is often referred to as OSG (and all code resides in a similarly named namespace) could we go ahead and make them synonyms of each other? I fear that otherwise the tag might created again.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks for the retagging.

Since [osg](/questions/tagged/osg) doesn't exist anymore, there's no point in making it a synonym. A 3-letter acronym that isn't massively popular has a high risk of being ambiguous, and is in any case unclear to the unitiated. Acronyms should be used when the acronym is better-known than the full expansion. Otherwise it's best to stick to the full name.

Comment: Well, in fact the library is often referred to as OSG (and it is the namespace used throughout the code). I fear that it will simply be created again.

Comment: And my fears have been proven wrong. So there you go. ;)

Comment: Test comment (for issue discussed in chat).